# How to send data alerts based while using Power Bi report server (on-premise)

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I'm creating some reports and dashboard using Power Bi Desktop and by publishing my reports on Power Bi report server (So the Data alerts feature doesn't exist in my version).

But I want to create some data alert so I can notify the user for some anomalies that may occur (Like if their products stay in the stock for more than 120 days).

I tried to work with SQL Server email with HTML formatted body but the attached file is in .txt format and the file size is limited.

```
 Declare @HTMLbody nvarchar(max),
         @NumChassis varchar(100),
         @Marque varchar(100),
       @Modele varchar(100),
         @Finition varchar(100),
         @SQL nvarchar(max)
         set @SQL =''
         Set @HTMLbody = '<!DOCTYPE html> <head><title>Aging stock notification</title></head><body>'
         set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + '<center><h1> Notification des véhicules en stock</h1></center> '
         set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + '<center><p> Vous pouvez visualisez la  liste des chassis en stock depuis plus de 120 jours pièces jointes  </p> </center>'
         set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + ' <center> '



  set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + @SQL + '</table> </center> <center><a href="http://Dashboard><b>Voir plus de détails sur le tableau de bord</b> </a></center> '

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'Admin_smtp',  
   @body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'Em@il',  
@body =  @HTMLbody,  
   @query = 'select top(10) a.NUM_CHASSIS,a.MARQUE,a.MODELE,a.FINITION ,DATEDIFF(DAY, a.DATE_FIN_OF, GETDATE()) as Age  from [DashboardPowerBi].[dbo].[BI_SVC_PROD_FIN_OF] as a
 join [DashboardPowerBi].[dbo].[BI_SVC_INCADEA_STOCK_VN] as b 
  on a.NUM_CHASSIS = b.VIN
  where b.CMD_Vente_Incadea = 0 and b.Fact_Av_Incadea =1 and DATEDIFF(DAY, a.DATE_FIN_OF, GETDATE()) > 120',
@subject = 'Aging Stock notification',
   @attach_query_result_as_file=1 ;
```

I tried also to create a job with an ETL: Talend Open studio which worked fine for me. yet, I find it a complex process and I read that Talend is not the best tool to send emails.
[image]

I need your recommendations and suggestions on how I can solve this with an effective way

Comment: hi i think it's a  general open query and architecture propose. So i didn't say if stackoverflow was the best site to post thoses. In my case i'm using some piece of code (like C#, .net console app or bash or powershell) and query a stored procedure they have put on Scheduled task in other Server. So i think exist multiple solution and it depend on architecture and other point..

Comment: I thought about developing the notification with php too but i'm a bit confused

Comment: @M_M have you tryed specifying the extension through `@query_attachment_filename` or does this overwrite the extension with `.txt`?